# How to create custom switch in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, customization

Flutter provides a default switch. But I want to customize it accordingly to my UI. How can customized flutter default switch?

[image]

Comment: Can you share image of switch which types of  switch you need.

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch @Mehedi Hasan

Comment: @Assassin This package is not perfect solving my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a custom switch. I used this class. [Custom switch class](https://gist.github.com/jpmehedi/a1f170bdd7b5fb5c0adb6fe97638644e)

You can customize the height and width of the switch, the border radius of the switch, the colors, the toggle size, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. It was really helpful. The best thing was, I wanted to customized with border not only colors and sizes. Your code helped me doing that.

Answer (score 3):

i was looking for a way to implement a custom switch but i only found the answer on this one that doesn't use a package.

i thought it is too complicated so i made this one instead it is essentially the same but a bit simpler and i wanted to share it.

FYI i made the colors hardcoded feel free to send them as trackColors, thumbColors. active and inactive it will animate that as well as many other aspects animatedContainers are indeed awesome.

```
class StyledSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(bool isToggled) onToggled;

  const StyledSwitch({Key? key, required this.onToggled}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StyledSwitch> createState() => _StyledSwitchState();
}

class _StyledSwitchState extends State<StyledSwitch> {
  bool isToggled = false;
  double size = 30;
  double innerPadding = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    innerPadding = size / 10;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => isToggled = !isToggled);
        widget.onToggled(isToggled);
      },
      onPanEnd: (b) {
        setState(() => isToggled = !isToggled);
        widget.onToggled(isToggled);
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        height: size,
        width: size * 2,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(innerPadding),
        alignment: isToggled ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: isToggled ? Colors.blue.shade100 : Colors.grey.shade300,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: size - innerPadding * 2,
          height: size - innerPadding * 2,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            color: isToggled ? Colors.blue.shade600 : Colors.grey.shade500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is an output test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDbm.gif)